# 1 Activity, 2 Fragments and setting orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-orientation

I have an Activity where the 1st Fragment (whose orientation is locked) solicits input from a user. This data is used to determine how to orient the 2nd Fragment. This orientation will also be locked.

I am guessing I will have to make a call to `setRequestedOrientation(                      ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)` either from the Activity or the 2nd Fragment.

My question is where best to do this. Does it really make a difference? Can this action be performed w/o undergoing an Activity restart?

Comment: So does it make a difference if this is done in the Activity, Fragment.onCreate(), Fragment.onCreateView()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If changing the `setRequestedOrientation` state requires the screen to rotate then it will restart the activity.

For example if you request `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` while the screen is in landscape, it will restart.
However it will not restart if the phone is already in that orientation.